# Angular ui-router doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular, i've been trying to use ui-router in this project, but ui-view doesn't show anything, did i miss something?.
I'm trying to build a mean app, the folder structure is the following:
The app folder is where the angular app is located.
[image: Structure app]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="TimeWaste">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="">
            <input type="text" ng-model="login.email">
            <input type="password" ng-model="login.password">
            <button>Login</button>
            <a ui-sref="signUp">Create an account</a>
        </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<body>


<div ui-view></div>

</body>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/signup/signup-controller.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is the app.js

```
(function()
{
angular.module('TimeWaste',['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider)
    {
        $stateProvider
            .state('signup',{
                url:"/signup",
                templateUrl: "app/signup/signup.html",
                controller:"SignupController"
            })
    })
  }());
```

the signup.html view

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <strong>Email Address:</strong>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newUser.email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <strong>Password:</strong>
        <input type="password" ng-model="newUser.password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="createUser()">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and the signup controller

```
(function()
{
  angular.module('TimeWaste')
    .controller('SignupController',       ['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state){

    }]);

}());
```

Comment: Have you checked your [Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) for any errors?

Comment: you have a typo in <a ui-sref="signUp">Create an account</a>  So change "signUp" to "signup"

Comment: I fixed the ui-sref problem, but it still not showing the view, there's no error on the console

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your path in templateUrl should be `signup/signup.html` by the way, since you're in `app.js` and it's a child of app folder

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez there can be many thing so best way to resolve it putting an error event for ui-router so u can see what is wrong in the error object...

Answer (score 0):

It may typo and path missing !!

in html used `<a ui-sref="signUp">Create an account</a>` but in `$stateProvider` used `signup` so need to change `signUp` to `signup`.

and I assume your `app.js` is in `app` directory because you use

`<script src="app/app.js"></script>` in home page.

if right then your template path need to change `templateUrl: "signup/signup.html",`

However you can configure `ui.route` to be case insensitive.

like:

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlMatcherFactoryProvider,)
    {
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false); 

        $stateProvider
            .state('signup',{
                url:"/signup",
                templateUrl: "signup/signup.html",
                controller:"SignupController"
        })
})
```